# What's the advantage of the inet datatype in Cassandra vs a plain text string?

Tags: php, datatypes, cassandra

What is the `inet` datatype really for? The documentation refers to its usage having something to do with Python but I'm not much of a Python guy so that aspect is beyond me. Is there any advantage to using `inet` over just a plain text representation of an IP and what is it?

If its pertinent, I'm using PHP 5.6 and Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a special datatype for storing ip addresses. It would be more compact that the string representation of the same information as well as type safe.

```
inet    An IP address. It can be either 4 bytes long (IPv4) or 
16 bytes long (IPv6). There is no inet constant, 
IP address should be inputed as strings
```

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't run across Apache's docs on Cassandra so a second thank you for exposing me to this doc page.